# Counting vowels and appending to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

How would I go about summing up occurrences of vowels in a list in Python, then appending it to the dictionary according to the vowel count?

Here's my current attempt:

```
def vowelCount(input1):
    d = {'half vowels': None,
         'mostly consonant': None, 'mostly vowels': None}
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    con = 0
    for word in input1:
        print(word, len(word))
        for vowel in vowels:
            if vowel in word:
                print(word.count(vowel))
                # FIXME: I can't figure out how to
                # sum up the occurrences
                #if (word.count(vowel)) < len(word):
                #    print(word)
```

And here's a description of what I expect:

```
its 3

1

a 1

1

death 5

1

1

trap 4

1

its 3

1

a 1

1

suicide 7

1

2

1

rap 3

1

we 2

1

gotta 5

1

1

get 3

1

out 3

1

1

while 5

1

1

were 4

2

young 5

1

1
```

Comment: It would help if your desired output was a little clearer. You don't need to give so many examples - three or four would do - but mentioning the desired resultant dictionary would go a long way in making your question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your code as a base, you just need to modify some things as stated below. The result is your `d` dictionary with all words properly sorted in. This version takes a sentence as input which splits into a list at spaces:

```
def vowelCount(input1):
    d = {'halfVowels': [], 'mostlyConsonant': [], 'mostlyVowels': []}
    input1 = input1.split(' ')  # split sentence at spaces
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    for word in input1:
        con = 0  # reset counter for every word
        for letter in word: # iterating over the vowels would give wrong results here
            if letter in vowels:
                con += 1
        if con > len(word)-con:  # sort everythin in
            d['mostlyVowels'].append(word)
        elif con == len(word)-con:
            d['halfVowels'].append(word)
        else:
            d['mostlyConsonant'].append(word)
    return d  # return the dictionary
```

This code would give the following results:

```
print(vowelCount('its a death trap its a suicide rap'))
{'mostlyVowels': ['a', 'a', 'suicide'], 'halfVowels': [], 'mostlyConsonant': ['its', 'death', 'trap', 'its', 'rap']}
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that!

Comment: @deborah-digges: You're welcome! I was not able to comment on your answer at that time, but now we have a couple of nice solutions here.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your question but I'm not 100% sure, so apologies if this isn't what you're looking for. There are a finite number of vowels, so you can determine how many vowels there are quite easily by defining those vowels and keeping an active count.

```
def vowel_count(s):
    """
    @param s is a string representing the contents of the list
    """

    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    counts = {}
    for v in vowels:
       counts[v] = 0
    for c in s:
       if c in vowels:
           counts[c] += 1
    return counts
```

Something along those lines?

Comment: you can spare some lines creating the dict directly, and also apply `.lower()` to take in account the upper letters

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, I this is what you would want.For each word, reset the vowelcount to 0 and proceed to find the number of vowels in the word. Based on this count, construct your dictionary D.

```
def vowelCount(input1):

    d={'half vowels': [], 'mostly constant':[], 'mostlyVowels':[]}
    vowels='aeiou'
    for word in input1:
        print(word, len(word))
        vowelcount = 0
        for vowel in vowels:
            if vowel in word:
                vowelcount += word.count(vowel)
        if vowelcount == len(word)/2:
           d["half vowels"].append(word)
        elif vowelcount < len(word)/2:
            d["mostly constant"].append (word)
        else:
             d["mostlyVowels"].append(word)  
    return d
```

However, this code is a mess. Try to separate these into independent testable functions:

```
def vowelcount(word):
    # ...
    return number of vowels in word

def constructSummary(listOfWords):
    d = { }
    for word in words:
        count = vowelcount(word)
        # .. If else ladder based on count 
        # construct d based on count
    return d
```

Comment: the vowel count for a word with a repeating value isnt being accounted for. For example 'suicide' gives a vowel count of 3 instead of four because it ignores the second 'i'. Although if "vowelcount +=1" is changed to "vowelcount += word.count(vowel)" that problem is solved.

Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: You're right! I've updated the answer to correctly count repeating vowels. Thank you!